# Button on a grid and both Grid and button has event handler so how can we differentiate it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

there is a button on a grid material UI and both grid and button have event handler so how can we differentiate it? by using event.currentTarget or by some other way? because when we click on button the div onclick is also being triggered. i want this if grid is clicked a specific function execute and when button is clicked the button onclick must be executed. kindly tell me how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand the need to have the grid onClick event. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: onclick on grid is for collapse and a button on a grid is for another query

Answer (score 0):

you can use wrapper functions, its two functions in one `onClick` prop like this you said you use `onClick` grid for collapse, you can write another function in that handleClick function like this :

```
const wrapperCloseFunction = () => {
    props.close(key)
    props.setDeleteMethod(deleteModels.single)
}

<Button
      sx={{
           width: '129px',
           color: 'black.0',
           fontSize: '16px',
           backgroundColor: 'white',
           height: '36px',
           borderRadius: '8px'
          }}
       onClick={wrapperCloseFunction} />
```